# Mailto template works when "paste in urlbar" but not after "registration and click on mailto link"

Tags: firefox-addon

This is the weirdest thing. I have a Hotmail/Live mail/Outlook mail account. So the template to start composing an email is this:

`http://mail.live.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=%s`

I have tested adding the Gmail handler template of `https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s` with the code below and then clicking on a `mailto:` link and it works fine.

To replicate:

1. Please run this code, it will create the Outlook handler and set it to active.

   ```
   //start - create handler
   var handler = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/web-handler-app;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIWebHandlerApp);
   handler.name = 'Outlook Live';
   handler.uriTemplate = 'http://mail.live.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=%s';
   //end - create handler

   //start - add handler
   var eps = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/external-protocol-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIExternalProtocolService);
   var handlerInfo = eps.getProtocolHandlerInfo('mailto');
   handlerInfo.possibleApplicationHandlers.appendElement(handler, false);
   //end - add handler

   //start - set as active handler
   handlerInfo.preferredAction = Ci.nsIHandlerInfo.useHelperApp; //Ci.nsIHandlerInfo has keys: alwaysAsk:1, handleInternally:3, saveToDisk:0, useHelperApp:2, useSystemDefault:4
   handlerInfo.preferredApplicationHandler = handler;
   handlerInfo.alwaysAskBeforeHandling = false;
   //end - set as active handler

   var hs = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/handler-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIHandlerService);
   hs.store(handlerInfo);
   ```
2. Click on a mailto link. For example I clicked on "Support E-mail" on my addon page here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mailtowebmails/ the link is mailto:noitidart
3. It opens in Hotmail but the to is `mailto:`:

   [image: funky to]

Why does the mailto not work in step 3?

If you just paste into the url bar: http://mail.live.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=noitidart@gmail.com it loads up fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web protocol handler will send the full `.spec` of the URI, meaning it will send `mailto:abc@example.org` and **not** just `abc@example.org`.

Apparently the http live.com endpoint doesn't handle that.

However, in a shocking twist, the https live.com endpoint does handle it, i.e. `https://mail.live.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=mailto:abc@example.org` will extract the right address from the `mailto:` URI.

So, update your web protocol template URI to the following and you should be fine (until MS messes up again):

```
https://mail.live.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=%s
```

Comment: Oh my gosh `https` that's all it took? Wow thanks man so much these tiny quirky bugs are so hard to find!